# Multiview application crash

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I made a multiview based application. My app has 3 views. The first is a disclaimer notice. When the user agrees it takes them to the main menu. From there, if they click a button, they will be taken to the respective views. One view is where the user can enter values (upon which a calculation is done). When I click the button to go to that view my app crashes and the following code gets highlighted. I followed this [video tutorial](http://youtu.be/ph3XhJD8QAI).

```
 [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES]; along with the program received a SIGABRT message !
```

Checking the debugger showed me the following message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<gainview 0x6a10d10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label1.'`

This is my full code:

**code in the disclaimer view**

```
-(IBAction)switchtoview2:(id)sender{

    secondview *second = [[secondview alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

**code in the main menu (i get the error when pressing the button in this view)**

```
-(IBAction)swichtogain:(id)sender{
    gainview *second = [[gainview alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES]; //debugger highlights this line !     
}
```

When hitting the button it is supposed to go to another view where I have few buttons: UItextfields and few pickers.

Comment: Please show us the code that gets executed when you tap your button.

Comment: Can you show how "second" is created?  You said view above, but it needs to be a ViewController -- that's the first thing to check (they're two separate things).

Comment: I left my work back in university ( i don't have a mac at home ! ) i'll post the code on monday. thanks guys ! :)

Comment: i found wat was causing the problem. one of the uitextfields had two references. i had to remove the old one and it fixed the issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly likely, you have a problem with one of your nib files, or a mismatch between nib definition and your classes.

In the nib associated to the controller that you are trying to show modally, check:

1. that all connections among outlets and objects are correct;
2. that the class identity of you nib objects is the one you expect to be (specifically for your controller/file's owner);
3. that your Objective C classes have all their `IBOutlet`s defined.

If you need more help, you should post some more code...

Comment: Thank you so much. One of my UItextfield had two references. i forgot to delete the old one and that was causing the problem !. I should be more careful next time ! xD